# RavenDb - The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized

Tags: asp.net, ravendb

I'm experimenting a bit with ravendb.

When testing on a remote Win2008 r2 server, with ravendb as an IIS website, I receive the error "The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized".

- On my local dev machine, everything works as expected
- ONLY when trying to connect to the DB in another test site. (ravendb client api)
- when trying to connect in a webbrowser, http://localhost:9999/docs/tests/1 ex. everything works as expected
- When connecting from my dev machine (with the test site) to the online server, no problem as well. So only on the remote server, where test site and db site are on the same machine.
- I'm using a connectionstring as explained in http://ravendb.net/documentation/client-api/connection-string: Url=http://localhost:9999;user=xxxxxx;password=yyyyy

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here:

http://ayende.com/blog/15361/the-evil-tricks-of-ldquo-it-works-on-my-machinerdquo-in-reverse
http://ayende.com/blog/16385/more-auth-issues-0xc000006d-on-windows-2008-r2

Answer (score 1):

Your windows authentication may use kerberos behind the scenes especially if the remote webserver is talking to another remote machine hosting RavenDB.

You may either setup kerberos correctly (SetSPN....) or disable windows authentication and use another authentication method.

I experienced this issue myself, you may want to read my [full story](http://blog.fabse.net/2012/08/31/solution-to-the-credentials-supplied-to-the-package-were-not-recognized/).